# RuntimeError: No application found.This only happens when I query from db

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I am creating a Python Object that all static data in the db. I would like to have one instance of this across the Application that I can access by using an "import" variable. In the code, I have multiple DB queries happening but as soon as I use "country.query.all()" I get the runtime error.

I have tried using with app.app_context() only to be greeted to "Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'api' from 'App.api.routes'
 Edit: I am using blue prints this is why you will see App.api.routes

```
getinfo.py  
       def create():
    class Country:
        def __init__(self,id, name,iso):
            self.id= id
            self.name = name
            self.iso = iso
            self.providers = get_providers_by_id(id)

    class Provider:
        def __init__(self, id, name):
            self.id = id
            self.name = name
            self.products = get_product_by_id(id)


    b = []

    countries = country.query.all()

    for row in countries:

        b.append(Country(row.id, row.name,row.iso))


    return b
items = create()



routes.py
    From App.getinfo import items

Error: RuntimeError: No application found. Either work inside a view function or push an application context. countries = country.query.all()


getinfo.py (changes to try to fix)
app = create_app()
with app.app_context():
   items= create()  

Error: ImportError: cannot import name 'api' from 'App.api.routes'
```

I am hoping to not get this issue and to have the option to use the variable "items" as an instance in my routes.

Edit #2: Tried using current_app

```
getinfo.py (Try to fix #2)
from flask import current_app

with current_app.app_context():
   test = create()
RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information.
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no such terms `App.api.routes` from your shared code, so we can't help you here. Just do a full search on the project path and fix the import error.

You were right on using the application context, however better use `current_app` instead of re-creating an new app:

`from flask import current_app`

Comment: My apologies. I am using blueprints, this is why you will see App.api.routes. Secondly, using current_app gives me.     RuntimeError: Working outside of application context.

This typically means that you attempted to use functionality that needed
to interface with the current application object in some way. To solve
this, set up an application context with app.app_context().  See the
documentation for more information. I made the changes in my post.

Comment: @user2137896 I think the issue is on your project architecture, you didn’t understand how to use flask app/blueprint in the correct way. I suggest you download/copy the project templates here : https://github.com/imwilsonxu/fbone